# node mongoose update a value within an object in a collection

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a function that will edit an order.  My order collection in mongoose is shown in the picture below.  I'm trying to update the product quantity, but I do not know how to update the new quantity for the product object and save it back to the database.

[image]

If I was trying to update the orderTotal I could just do `order.orderTotal = newValue;` and then call the `order.save()` but I'm not sure how to get to the path Order.shoppingCart.products.(guid).quantity in order to save a new value as the quantity.  I'm sure i can use a for loop but within that for loop how would I save the product quantity to the database?

```
    order.save((err) => {
        if (err)
            console.log("Error", err);

        req.flash('success', `Order id ${order.id} updated`);
        res.redirect(`/orders/user/${order.user}`);
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide ```document``` ? So , I can get better understanding of your problem.